# What's wrong with lldb/gdb, ignoring first sleep() statement in OS X?

Tags: c++, gdb, fork, sleep, lldb

I am running into the following problem on the latest version of OS X 10.8.2, with latest Xcode 4.5.

Take the following simple piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (0 == pid)
    {
        std::cout << "Child process!\n";

        exit(0);
    }
    else if (-1 == pid)
    {
        std::cout << "Error forking.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "In parent, created pid " << pid << ".\n";

        sleep(100000);      // Sleep a long time - GDB/LLDB ignores the first sleep statement
        sleep(3);           // Sleep 3 more seconds - GDB/LLDB doesn't ignore the second sleep statement

        std::cout << "Done in parent!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile it using `clang++ foo.cpp -o foo` or `g++ foo.cpp -o foo` and run it using `./foo`, it takes a long time to run, as expected.

Now do either `lldb ./foo` or `gdb ./foo`, then `run` and notice it completes in 3 seconds. Whenever either debugger is used, the first sleep statement is seemingly ignored.

Since Xcode uses lldb by default when running a project, pasting the above code into a blank Xcode project and doing Product->Run will have similar results.

I've tried the same experiment on a Linux machine with gdb 7.2, and the problem does *not* occur there.

Is this a bug in an older version of gdb that Apple uses (gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1822) ), or is it something else? Perhaps just my computer is messed up, if it doesn't happen to other OS X users?

Comment: Its definitely not just you. I cut/paste this verbatim to my Xcode, fired it up, and had the exact same results. Dude, thats f'ed up. I kept staring at your code looking for a bug but I just don't see any.

Comment: Are you setting gdb to follow the child or the parent or break on both or neither, gdb will follow the parent which finishes straight away.

Comment: I'm not doing anything other than what I mentioned in the question. The parent shouldn't finish straight away as it has 2 sleeps in there.

Comment: And the child process runs on its own outside the debugger - what do you expect?

Comment: I expect the parent process not to ignore the first sleep statement, just like what happens if you run the binary without a debugger. Is it wrong to expect that?

Comment: Have you tried a break at main() and stepped through the code - what happen then?

Comment: If I do that, the first `sleep(100000);` statement works as expected.

Comment: I have a feeling that the act of the child process exiting is making lldb/gdb send some sort of signal to the parent process, interrupting the first sleep. Could that be?

Comment: Just as I thought, adding a `sleep(15);` line to the child process causes the parent to last over 15 seconds.

So it seems, when being debugged by lldb/gdb, the child process exiting does something to the parent process.

But this doesn't occur on the Linux system with gdb 7.2 that I tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although many people do not use it, `sleep` actually has a return value.

`man 3 sleep`:

> RETURN VALUES
>
> ```
> If the sleep() function returns because the requested time has elapsed,
> the value returned will be zero.  If the sleep() function returns due
> to the delivery of a signal, the value returned will be the unslept amount
> (the requested time minus the time actually slept) in seconds.
> ```

sure enough, the expected value is returned considering the observed behavior.

Comment: You're right, thanks!

So, when debugged by lldb/gdb, the child process exiting is causing a signal to be sent to the parent process.

Then my question is, what signal is being sent, and why does it happen on OS X in gdb 6.3.50 but not on a Linux system with gdb 7.2?

Comment: @DmitriShuralyov there are a lot of differences in the two kernels; i'm not going to guess. instead… you may want to try installing a signal handler and then running without the debugger (because the debugger may intercept signals).

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to install a signal handler that intercepts all signals? Or do I have to set up each signal handler individually, and hopefully mention all of them (in order to catch the one that's being sent)?

Comment: @DmitriShuralyov not sure. i'd just install them. the standard signals are 1-30 -- but many would not apply here. process of elimination should be only a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due to the fact that any time the debugger wants to pause a process, if that process is in the middle of a system call (it is executing code in kernel-land), that system call is aborted EINTR style on Mac OS X.  I don't know how Linux systems handle this but that's what happens on Mac OS X.  If you run your program, and in a separate window attach to it with lldb and continue the process, you'll find that your sleep(100000); call is terminated as soon as execution resumes.  It seems like there must be a SIGCHLD signal being broadcast when the child process exits and that's causing the parent process to be interrupted by the debugger - but I'm not completely clear on what is leading to the long sleep() call being ended early in this specific case.